# Reload light box after struts validation action

Tags: validation, popup, struts, refresh, lightbox

I would like to load a light box (containing a form) with errors in it after struts validation fails. My problem is when I use forward, a page containing the errors is loaded. This is not really what I intended. I would like to have light box in the same page but only refreshed with errors.

I am using Struts1 (1.3)  and it would be great if there is any feature that permits to do so.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I ended up thinking that it is impossible to load the light box if not combined with AJAX technology. What I end up doing is call a javascript function when I validate my form. If you have any other solutions, I will be glad to consider them.

Thanks !